# Heap corruption from this method

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

I'm getting a heap corruption error whenever the following method is called:

```
bool TextureData::loadFromMemory(char* memData, int w, int h)
{   
    GLuint texId;

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &texId);

    glTextureId = static_cast<int>(texId);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId); // Bind the texture
    
    glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    memWidth = width = w;
    memHeight = height = h;

    int newPad = 0;//(4 - (w*4)%4)==4 ? 0 : (4 - (w*4)%4);
    int oldPad = 0;//(4 - (w*3)%4)==4 ? 0 : (4 - (w*3)%4);

    size_t size = (width+newPad)*height * 4;
    char* data = 0;

        data = new char[size];
        memcpy(data, memData, size * sizeof(char));         

    // Texture generation
    
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, memWidth, memHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        
    delete [] data;

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    return true;
}
```

Where the char* data array given to this method is generated like this:

```
int imageSize = width_ * height_ * 4;
data_ = new char[imageSize];

SDL_LockSurface(TextureImage);

for (Uint y = 0; y < height_; ++y)
{
    for (Uint x = 0; x < width_; ++x)
    {
        size_t currPixel = (y * width_ + x) * 4;

        SDL_Color rgb;
        Uint32 data = getPixel(TextureImage, x, y);
        SDL_GetRGB(data, TextureImage->format, &rgb.r, &rgb.g, &rgb.b);

        data_[currPixel] = (char)rgb.r;
        data_[currPixel + 1] = (char)rgb.g;
        data_[currPixel + 2] = (char)rgb.b;
        data_[currPixel + 3] = (char)255;
    }
}

SDL_UnlockSurface(TextureImage);
SDL_FreeSurface(TextureImage);
```

I can't figure out why the loadFromMemory method is causing a heap corruption and need a review, if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: I can't see any `loadFromMemory` calls in your second snippet. Maybe in-between those code fragmnets there is something wrong. Please provide a [MRE]

Comment: It's possible the corruption happens before the call to `loadFromMemory`, but is only detected during the `new` call within that function.

Comment: I thought about that but if I comment out this code it never happens. There is a singleton which is creating all of these.